# Using orderBy: How to sort an array of numbers and put any string values on the bottom?

Tags: angularjs

I've been at this for a while so I'll just post my issue and its answer in case anyone else stumbles in it.

I was trying to sort the following array by the duration in descending order:

```
{
  0:
  {
    first_name: "Tom"
    duration: "00:50"
  }
  1:
  {
    first_name: "Bob"
    duration: "01:30"
  }
  2:
  {
    first_name: "Dan"
    duration: "< 1 min"
  }
}
```

The correct order should be Bob - Tom - Dan, however when using AngularJS filter orderBy `orderBy($scope.students,'duration',true);` I got Dan - Bob - Tom.

Comment: what are the strings ?

Comment: @AnikIslamAbhi can you clarify what you're asking about Anik

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The way I got around that is by writing a function that would differentiate between the unique string and the actual number:

```
var orderByExp = function(student) {
    if(student.duration.match(/\d\d:\d\d/)) {
        return student.duration;
    }
    else{
        return "";
    }
}
```

And passing that function as the expression:

`orderBy($scope.students,orderByExp,true);`

That way if I get anything other than "xx:xx" then it is treated as an empty string.